# adding too many number of parameters in store process

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, stored-procedures, sqlcommand

here is my problem , i want to use a store process in my app but there are too many argument, i'm looking for a simple way to use all my argument in my store process: 
I was thinking of a solution where i use propertyinfo
here is my program:

have you a solution to reduce this process ?
thanks in advance

Comment: Create a list of string and add your @ params in it. Next run a for loop to construct a list of parameters and add it to command.

Comment: Use one of the shorter overloads: `cmd2.Parameters.Add("@TK_Ty", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 10;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would recommend using a `Dictionary<string, object>` instead of a `List<KeyValuePair<string, object>`, since a Dictionary already implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<T,T>`.

Second, you don't need to explicitly create each parameter, you can use almost any overload of `SqlCommand.Parameters.Add` since they return the `SqlParameter` object back to the calling method, allowing you to specify the parameter value like this:

```
cmd2.Parameters.Add("@ParamName", SqlDBType.Int).Value = ParamValue;
```

In this case I wouldn't even use the Parameters list, but just add them directly like this:

```
cmd2.Parameters.Add("@TK_Num", SqlDBType.Int).Value = ticket.TK_Ty;
cmd2.Parameters.Add("@TK_Mouv", SqlDBType.Int).Value = ticket.TK_Mouv;
cmd2.Parameters.Add("@TK_Im", SqlDBType.Int).Value = ticket.TK_Immatriculation;
....
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [TVP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx) . It helps to pass table parameter into sproc and make it simpler to access.

By using TVP ,you can use it as many times. No need to create every single parameters from code.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.